# Several asp.net apps in single Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I got two working asp.net projects - API and site itself. I am trying to deploy it to one instance of Azure App service. But I got working configurations only if I deploy it to app's subfolder, and create non root virtual applications, e.g.:

[image]

But if I am trying to make root app for site:

[image]

I got problem with API project - it fails to work, cause it is trying to load Web.config from 'root' virtual application:

[image]

How could I made virtual app to load its own config file - not from the root app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inheritInChildApplications in your application(not api) web.config to stop inheritance.

Wrap `system.web` section with location element with `inheritInChildApplications` set to false

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
    <system.web> 
    … 
    </system.web> 
  </location>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingASPNETWebconfigInheritanceWhenMixingVersionsOfChildApplications.aspx)